# Closing an electron window when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, electron

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I understand that I need to use BrowserWindow.close(), but I don't understand how to do that outside of main.js.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here use this.

```
window.top.close();
```

It works just fine wherever you are inside of the electron app.

Comment: All this searching and no solution was even remotely as simple as that... Thanks so much.

Comment: Haha, it's that simple, :)